# How do you replace a value in a 2D list in python?

Tags: python

Lets say I have this example:

```
Num = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

How would I replace a number in this list using `list.append()` and a user input for the index position?

For example: I would like to replace a 4 in the array with a 7.

Comment: `append` is not meant for updating but appending

Comment: lI thought you were able to replace values using it, do you have another solutuion?

Answer (score 3):

You don't use `.append`.  You use assignment (possibly slice assignment).  `Num[1]` will refer to `[4,5,6]`.  `Num[1][0]` will refer to the 4 ... so`Num[1][0] = 7` will do what you want.

Comment: oh ok, is there a function or command to replace instead if append?

Comment: @Karim You *could* use the del command and the insert function, but why would you want to, rather than just using assignment?

Answer (score 0):

```
Num[1][0]= 7
```

should do the trick... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will replace each 4 with 7, effectively recreate the list. It doesn't matter anymore where 4 is...it can be on any position of the list

```
new_num = [[k if k != 4 else 7 for k in i] for i in num]
```

output

```
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`.append()` is only for inserting items at the end of the array.

Simple way would be, if you now where the data is:

```
num = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
num[1][0] = <new_value>
```

If you want to replace all 4 or the first 4 in the array, you could iterate it like this:

```
looked = <number>
new_value = <number>
for array_data in num:
   if (looked in array_data):
      array_data[array_data.index(looked)] = new_value
```

For a function replace:

```
# This will replace the first <value> found
def replace(L, new, old):
   for array_data in num:
      if (old in array_data):
         array_data[array_data.index(old)] = new

num = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
replace(num, 7, 4)

[[1,2,3], [7,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

For replacing all value, just use lambda functions:

```
new_num = lambda x, y, z: [[k if k != z else y for k in i] for i in x]
new_num(num, 7, 4)

[[1,2,3], [7,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

Comment: oh ok, what function is it to replace?

Comment: edited, with a function